# is there a tool who provide an abstract interface of all the pm tools?

Tags: apt, package-management, pacman

In GNU distros, you can meet many kinds of package management tools.

apt pacman  yum dnf pkg, etc.

Is there a tool who provides an abstract API for all the tools?

Answer (score 1):

This is what [PackageKit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/) tries to do:

> The actual nuts-and-bolts distro tool (dnf, apt, etc) is used by PackageKit using compiled and scripted helpers. PackageKit isn't meant to replace these tools, instead providing a common set of abstractions that can be used by standard GUI and text mode package managers.
>
> […]
>
> Formally, PackageKit is a D-Bus abstraction layer that allows the session user to manage packages in a secure way using a cross-distro, cross-architecture API.